# ImageView click best practice

Tags: android, onclick, imageview, onclicklistener

I am a newbie in Andoird.

In my case, I have a scenario that when click certain part of an image it will trigger onclick events. I tried to detecte the position when the onTouch is fired, it works, but I think it's not a standard implementation, so what is the best practice for such case?

thanks.

here is codes like:

imgView.setOnTouchListener((OnTouchListener) new OnTouchListener(){

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 
    if(isIn(event.getX(), event.getY(), 124,3,221,36)){ 
        ShowMemberInfo(R.string.app_m01); 
    } else if(isIn(event.getX(), event.getY(), 8,155,72,181)){
         .. 
    } 
    return true; 
} 
private boolean isIn(float x, float y, int fx, int fy, int tx, int ty) { 
    return x<tx && x > fx && y<ty && y>fy; 
}
```

Comment: can you show us your implementation so we can know if it's or it isn't a standard implementation or if there is a best practice?

Comment: I had modified my answer. :) Maybe you can try to use Rect to define your custom detect region and call contains() to check whether the touch point is inside the area or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)

Comment: this, this is really helpful... Below link may be a better approach... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137657/onclicklistener-issues-after-imagebutton-moved-after-translateanimation)

Answer (score 0):

Simply implement `onClickListener()` for your ImageView.

Easiest way to implement onClick event is to include **`android:onClickMe="methodName"`** inside your `<ImageView>` in XML layout and define that method inside your activity file.

For example:

```
public void methodName(View v)
{
  ....
  ....

   // do whatever you want for click even ton imageview
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect the position where user touched(Relative to the ImageView user touched), you can get the touch point from MotionEvent object.

Try to register a touch event listener for the ImageView and get the touched point position from MotionEvent object's getX() and getY() methods when touch event is triggered. And then define a rectangular area and using contains() to check whether the touch point is inside the area or not.

```
ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
img.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.w("Hit test", "is hit? "+isIn(event.getX(),event.getY(),0,0,120,120));
        return false;
    }

});

private boolean isIn(float x, float y, int fx, int fy, int tx, int ty){
    return new Rect(fx,fy,tx,ty).contains((int)x,(int)y);
}
```

Hope this will be helpful to you. :)